# How change status of configured network and recover networkId from NetworkConfiguration list of WifiManager?

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

I was developing an app where I try to create a wifi interface, using WifiConfiguration list of WifiManager:

I try to make something like this:

MainActivity.kt

```
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
       private val viewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels()
       @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          setUI()
          processWifiConfiguration(applicationContext)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun processWifiConfiguration(context: Context) {

        val wifiEnterpriseConfig = WifiEnterpriseConfig()
        val wifiConfiguration = WifiConfiguration()
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.eapMethod = WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.phase2Method = Phase2.MSCHAPV2
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.caCertificate = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.anonymousIdentity = null
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.identity = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_USER +"\""
        wifiEnterpriseConfig.password = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.enterpriseConfig = wifiEnterpriseConfig
        wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_SSID +"\""
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedKeyManagement.set(KeyMgmt.IEEE8021X)
        wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey ="\""+BuildConfig.WIFI_PASS+"\""

        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP)
        wifiConfiguration.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP)

        try {
           viewModel.launchWifiConfiguration(context = context, info = wifiConfiguration)
       }catch (e:NullPointerException){
           Log.d("es.paytef", "configuredNetworks esta a null")
           e.printStackTrace()
       }

    }
```

So in my viewModel method:

SharedViewModel.kt

```
private val wifiManager: WifiManager =
        context.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

    private val _isLoading: MutableStateFlow<Boolean> = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val isLoading: StateFlow<Boolean> = _isLoading.asStateFlow()

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    fun launchWifiConfiguration(context: Context, info: WifiConfiguration) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _isLoading.emit(true)
            if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
                wifiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                wifiManager.callerConfiguredNetworks.add(info)
                    connectWifi(
                        context = context,
                        wifiConfiguration = info
                    )
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
            } else {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return@launch
                }
                if(wifiManager.configuredNetworks != null) {
                    //add the network
                    wifiManager.addNetwork(
                        info
                    )
                    //Enable all the interface
                    wifiManager.configuredNetworks.map {
                        it.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED
                    }
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "size after adding: ${wifiManager.configuredNetworks.size}")
                    Log.d(
                        "es.paytef",
                        "adding network with SSID: ${info.SSID}"
                    )
                }else{
                    Log.d("es.paytef", "Configured networks esta a null")
                }
                try {
                   connectWifi(
                       context = context,
                       wifiConfiguration = info
                    )
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("es.paytef", e.message ?: e.localizedMessage)
                    _isLoading.emit(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun connectWifi(
        context: Context,
        wifiConfiguration: WifiConfiguration,
    ) {
                Log.d(
        "es.paytef",
        "adding network via Android Enterprise Config with SSID: ${wifiConfiguration.SSID}"
        )
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        Log.d("es.paytef", "configuredNetwork after adding: ${wifiManager.configuredNetworks}")
        Log.d("es.paytef", "My wifi" + wifiConfiguration.status)
        // val networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration)
        val ssid = getNetworkId(wifiConfiguration.SSID)
        Log.d("es.paytef", "NetworkId: $ssid")
        Log.d("es.paytef", "wifiManager.isWifiEnabled: ${wifiManager.isWifiEnabled}")
            wifiManager.disconnect()
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(ssid, true) // this initiates the connection
            wifiManager.reconnect()
            Log.d("es.paytef", "Conecta el wifi a partir de red ya conectada")

    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getNetworkId(ssid: String): Int {
        val configurations = wifiManager.configuredNetworks
        for (config in configurations) {
            if (config.SSID != null && config.SSID.equals(ssid, true)) {
                Log.d("es.paytef", "resp en getNetworkId: ${config.networkId}")
                return config.networkId
            }
        }
        Log.d("es.paytef", "resp en getNetworkId:-1")
        return -1
    }
}
```

When I Log the avalaible network I see that my configured network is been added correctly:

```
- DSBLE ID: 3 SSID: "*******" PROVIDER-NAME: null BSSID: null FQDN: null PRIO: 0 HIDDEN: false
NetworkSelectionStatus NETWORK_SELECTION_PERMANENTLY_DISABLED
hasEverConnected: false
KeyMgmt: WPA_EAP IEEE8021X Protocols: WPA RSN
AuthAlgorithms: OPEN
PairwiseCiphers: TKIP CCMP
GroupCiphers: WEP40 WEP104 TKIP CCMP
PSK: *
Enterprise config:
anonymous_identity NULL
password <removed>
proactive_key_caching 1
identity ""******""
IP config:
IP assignment: DHCP
Proxy settings: NONE
cuid=10046 cname=********* luid=10046 lname=********** lcuid=0 userApproved=USER_UNSPECIFIED noInternetAccessExpected=false roamingFailureBlackListTimeMilli: 1000
recentFailure: Association Rejection code: 0
```

The "********" corresponde to confidencial data, but are strings.

But when I try to recover the id from my custom network the method get "getNetworkId", is returning -1, so the don't find it, beside if you take a look the property "NetworkSelectionStatus" is set to "NETWORK_SELECTION_PERMANENTLY_DISABLED", while in my other networks is set to "NETWORK_SELECTION_ENABLED", so they appears in the WiFi configuration panel.

Do you know how to change that property "NetworkSelectionStatus", from NetworkConfiguration returning by WifiManager instance, and why the method getNetworkId doesn't return the id?

What am I missing here?